# Haskell cannot compile regex code

Tags: regex, haskell, compiler-errors, ghc

When I tried to compile a program using GHC that uses Text.Regex I got following linking error. There is no error when I load it in GHCi.

```
myprog.o: In function `s149_info':
(.text+0x59b): undefined reference to `regexzmcompatzm0zi92_TextziRegex_mkRegex_closure'
myprog.o: In function `s14a_info':
(.text+0x5ec): undefined reference to `regexzmcompatzm0zi92_TextziRegex_splitRegex_closure'
myprog.o: In function `s14B_info':
(.text+0xf97): undefined reference to `__stginit_regexzmcompatzm0zi92_TextziRegex_'
myprog.o: In function `s14B_srt':
(.data+0xe0): undefined reference to `regexzmcompatzm0zi92_TextziRegex_mkRegex_closure'
myprog.o: In function `s14B_srt':
(.data+0xe4): undefined reference to `regexzmcompatzm0zi92_TextziRegex_splitRegex_closure'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to resolve this?
Google failed to provide help.
My GHC version is `Version 6.12.1, for Haskell 98, stage 2 booted by GHC version 6.12.1`

Comment: try to update GHC to 7.6.3

Comment: It's not in my hands. though I will try tell the admin guy.

Comment: What's the command you used to compile this program?

Comment: @kosmikus `ghc -o myprog myprog.hs`

Comment: Try `ghc --make -o myprog myprog.hs` instead.

Comment: @kosmikus It works. If you turn it into answer, I  can accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older versions of GHC, you have to pass the `--make` flag explicitly if you want to enable dependency tracking (which in this case includes linking in the correct libraries). Current versions of GHC use `--make` mode by default. So with GHC 6.12.1, you should use

```sh
ghc --make -o myprog myprog.hs
```

to compile your program.